# Can I add a SOQL query inside expression to fetch data from salesforce using informatica cloud

Tags: informatica-cloud

I have csv file as a source and salesforce as target in informatica cloud. To populate one of the fields on salesforce side, I want to write an IFF expression. If a=true, populate the field with 'xyz' but if a!=true, then run a SQOL query in salesforce, fetch the value and use that value to populate the field.

Is it possible to use a SOQL query inside the expression in informatica when salesforce is on the target side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A supported solution would be to use a Taskflow and first fetch the values from SFDC that you would query against in mapping prior to the insert mapping and in the insert mapping use a lookup in your mapping to do the transformation.

Comment: Thanks. So the actual task that I have created to load data into salesforce is Data synchronization task.Now in order to run a SOQL query and use it in expression, I have created a mapping to fetch salesforce data and load it into a temporary csv file. Now I have two csv files, one that has the actual data and other one that came via mapping by running SOQL query. Can my synchronization task take two csv files as source?

Comment: Use the CSV file as a look-up source for the value when a!=true. Update the file you are syncing into Salesforce then load it. Or use a mapping for the load instead of the data sync. There may be a way to make the change in the data synch but its been a couple of years and I don't recall all of the nuances of each.